# Replace text in textField with object name - Pymel

Tags: python, python-2.7, textfield, maya, pymel

I've realized that there were similar questions located

here:
[textfield query and prefix replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519653/textfield-query-and-prefix-replacing)

and

here:
[Python - Change the textField after browsing - MAYA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965843/python-change-the-textfield-after-browsing-maya)

However, these do not address the issue if you have two definitions and need the text in the `textField` to be queried (actually CHANGE the text in the textField).

I know from experience that doing what I have below in MelScript actually works, but for the sake of Python, and learning how to do it in Python, it seems to not work. Am I missing something? Do I need a lambda to get the name of the object selected and query the textField?

I have an example (a snip-bit of what needs to be fixed):

```
from pymel.core import *
def mainWindow():
    window('myWin')
    columnLayout(adj=1)
    button('retopoplz', ann='Select a Mesh to Retopologize', bgc=[.15,.15,.15],
           l='START RETOPOLOGY', c='Retopo(TextToMakeLive)')
    TextToMakeLive = textField(ann='Mesh Selected', bgc=[.2,0,0],
                               edit=0, tx='NONE')
    setParent('..')
    showWindow('myWin')
def Retopo(TextToMakeLive):
    #This tool selects the object to retopologize
    MakeLiveField = textField(TextToMakeLive, q=1, tx=1)
    MakeSelectionLive = (ls(sl=1))
    if MakeSelectionLive is None:
        warning('Please select an object to retopologize')
    if MakeSelectionLive == 1:
        TextToMakeLive = textField(TextToMakeLive, ed=1, 
                                   tx=MakeSelectionLive,
                                   bgc=[0,.2,0])
        shape = ls(s=MakeSelectionLive[0])
        setAttr((shape + '.backfaceCulling'),3)
        createDisplayLayer(n='RetopoLayer', num=1, nr=1)
        makeLive(shape)
        print('Retopology Activated!')
    else:
        warning('Select only ONE Object')
mainWindow()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI objects can always be edited -- including changing their commands -- as long as you store their names.  So your mainWindow() could return the name(s) of gui controls you wanted to edit again and a second function could use those names to change the looks or behaviors of the created objects.

However, this is all much easier if you use a python class to 'remember' the names of the objects and any other state information: it's easy for the class to 'see' all the relevant info and state.  Here's your original converted to classes:

```
from pymel.core import *
class RetopoWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = window('myWin')
        columnLayout(adj=1)
        button('retopoplz',ann='Select a Mesh to Retopologize', bgc=[.15,.15,.15],l='START RETOPOLOGY', c = self.do_retopo)
        self.TextToMakeLive=textField(ann='Mesh Selected', bgc=[.2,0,0],edit=0,tx='NONE')


    def show(self):
        showWindow(self.window)

    def do_retopo(self, *_):
        #This tool selects the object to retopologize
        MakeLiveField= textField(self.TextToMakeLive,q=1,tx=1)
        MakeSelectionLive=(ls(sl=1))
        if MakeSelectionLive is None:
            warning('Please select an object to retopologize')
        if len( MakeSelectionLive) == 1:
            TextToMakeLive=textField(self.TextToMakeLive,ed=1,tx=MakeSelectionLive,bgc=[0,.2,0])
            shape=ls(s=MakeSelectionLive[0])
            setAttr((shape+'.backfaceCulling'),3)
            createDisplayLayer(n='RetopoLayer',num=1,nr=1)
            makeLive(shape)
            print('Retopology Activated!')
        else:
            warning('Select only ONE Object')
```

RetopoWindow().show()

As for the callbacks: useful reference [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `command` flag AFTER you have created your `textField`  to be queried.

So you would do:

```
my_button = button('retopoplz',ann='Select a Mesh to Retopologize', bgc=[.15,.15,.15],l='START RETOPOLOGY')

TextToMakeLive=textField(ann='Mesh Selected', bgc=[.2,0,0],edit=0,tx='NONE')

button(my_button, e=True,  c=windows.Callback(Retopo, TextToMakeLive))
```

You were along the right thought chain when you suggested lambda. Pymel's Callback can be more advantageous over lambda here. Check out the docs: http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/zh_cn/PyMel/generated/classes/pymel.core.windows/pymel.core.windows.Callback.html

Comment: Hm... I'll give it a try in a moment and respond with what I get. I kept getting a NameError before when I tried to source my text change, obviously because the callback function I was using was not appropriate (I know enough to know this, but not enough to fix it).

What is the significance of "windows" in "windows.Callback"? 

EDIT:
[Finished my thought]

Comment: Well, I will say it works. The issue I'm encountering now is that it will not detect that it has selected an object. I guess that's better than not getting it to work at all... Thank you kartikg3!!

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. I meant to click it immediately, I got distracted (you know how it is, haha).

Comment: Kartikg3, I got another issue.

It states that there was an error executing Callback.
"<pymel.core.windows.Callback object at 0x0000000031188D68>"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\lib\site-packages\pymel\core\windows.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "<maya console>", line 283, in Retopo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'TextToMakeLive' referenced before assignment #