# Maya Python: How do i call on and edit attributes of an object in one function when that object was created in another function?

Tags: python, maya

## The Plan:

I've been working on a script for measuring the distance between 2 vertices that the user selects and scaling up or down that the object based on a desired length between those vertices.

## The Problem:

Error states that it cannot locate the textFieldButtonGrp object that I create in one of my functions.

i basically put my window format stuff into a single function:

```
def window_presets():
    '''
    presets for UI window
    '''
    if mc.window("Distance Scale Tool", exists=True):
        mc.deleteUI("Distance Scale Tool")
    mc.window("Distance Scale Tool", t="Distance Based Scale Tool")
    mc.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, 
                      columnAttach=(1, 'left', 0), 
                      columnWidth=[(1,100), (2,300)])
    mc.text(l="Current Length")
    current_length = mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Current Length", 
                                          editable=False, 
                                          text="{0}".format(refresh_current_dist()), 
                                          buttonLabel="Refresh", 
                                          buttonCommand=refresh_current_dist)

    mc.text(l="Desired Length")
    desired_length = mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Desired Length", 
                                          buttonLabel="Scale",  
                                          buttonCommand=scale_dist, 
                                          tcc=refresh_scale_factor)
                                 
    mc.showWindow()
```

i want the refresh button to  call another function that edits the textFieldButtonGrp that i created:

```
def refresh_textfield(distance):
    if mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Current Length", exists=True):
        mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Current Length", 
                              edit=True, 
                              text="{0}".format(distance))   
    else:
        print "Current Length dont exist"
```

but "Current Length".... it doesnt seem to exist....

same with "Desired Length"....

Heres the full script:

```
##  ((Ax - Bx)**2 + (Ay - By)**2 + (Az - Bz)**2)**0.5

import maya.cmds as mc
import math

def window_presets():
    '''
    presets for UI window
    '''
    if mc.window("Distance Scale Tool", exists=True):
        mc.deleteUI("Distance Scale Tool")
    mc.window("Distance Scale Tool", t="Distance Based Scale Tool")
    mc.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, 
                      columnAttach=(1, 'left', 0), 
                      columnWidth=[(1,100), (2,300)])
    mc.text(l="Current Length")
    current_length = mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Current Length", 
                                          editable=False, 
                                          text="{0}".format(refresh_current_dist()), 
                                          buttonLabel="Refresh",                          buttonCommand=refresh_current_dist)
    
    mc.text(l="Desired Length")
    desired_length = mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Desired Length", 
                                          buttonLabel="Scale",  
                                          buttonCommand=scale_dist, 
                                          tcc=refresh_scale_factor)
                                     
    mc.showWindow()
    

def get_object_name():
    selPoints = mc.ls(sl=True)
    obj_name = selPoints[0].split('.')[0]
    return obj_name
    
def get_coordinates():
    '''
    Gets coordinates of selected points and gets distance between them
    '''
    selPoints = mc.ls(sl=True)
    obj_name = get_object_name()
    print obj_name
    vtxCoordList = mc.xform(selPoints, 
                            query=True, 
                            translation=True, 
                            ws=True)
    Ax, Ay, Az = vtxCoordList[:-3]
    Bx, By, Bz = vtxCoordList[3:]
     
    return (Ax, Bx, Ay, By, Az, Bz)

def calculate_distance(Ax, Bx, Ay, By, Az, Bz):
    '''
    Determines distance between 2 coordinates on single mesh.
    
    Below are formulas for distance based on single axis:
     
    dx = ((Ax - Bx)**2)**0.5
    print "Distance on X axis is: {0}".format(dx) #distance on X axis
    dy = ((Ay - By)**2)**0.5
    print "Distance on Y axis is: {0}".format(dy) #distance on Y axis
    dz = ((Az - Bz)**2)**0.5
    print "Distance on Z axis is: {0}".format(dz) #distance on Z axis
    
    '''
    distance = math.sqrt((Ax - Bx)**2 + (Ay - By)**2 + (Az - Bz)**2)
         
    print "the distance between points is {0}".format(distance)
    
    return distance

def refresh_textfield(distance):
    if mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Current Length", exists=True):
        mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Current Length", 
                              edit=True, 
                              text="{0}".format(distance))   
    else:
        print "Current Length dont exist"
def refresh_current_dist():
    '''
    returns current distance
    '''

    current_coordinates = get_coordinates()
    current_distance = calculate_distance(*current_coordinates)

    refresh_textfield(current_distance)

    return current_distance


    
def refresh_scale_factor(sf):
    '''
    returns factor by which object will be scaled 
    ''' 
   
    current_distance = refresh_current_dist()
          
    scale_factor = (float(sf))/(float(current_distance))
    print "dist btwn pnts is d: {0}".format(current_distance)
    print "sf is {0}".format(sf)
    print "user input is {0}".format(sf)
    print "scale factor is {0}".format(scale_factor)
    print "-"*10
    return scale_factor

 
def scale_dist():
    '''
    scale object to match measurement
    '''
    user_input = float(mc.textFieldButtonGrp("Desired Length",
                                             query=True, 
                                             text=True))
    scale_factor = refreshScaleFactor(user_input)                                                                                          
    mc.makeIdentity(get_object_name(), 
                    apply=True, 
                    translate=1, 
                    rotate=1, 
                    scale=1, 
                    normal=0, 
                    preserveNormals=1)#freeze transformations
    mc.DeleteAllHistory()     
    mc.scale(scale_factor, scale_factor, scale_factor, get_object_name())
    print "you scaled by {0}".format(scale_factor)
    mc.makeIdentity(get_object_name(), 
                    apply = True, 
                    translate=1, 
                    rotate=1, 
                    scale=1, 
                    normal=0, 
                    preserveNormals=1)#freeze transformations



if __name__ == '__main__':
    window_presets()
```

Comment: You can look over this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609450/maya-python-using-data-from-ui/29612845#29612845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Remove the space in `"Current Length"` and this will fix your error.

**Naming notes:**

Consider applying labels the same naming as the one you are using on functions. I usually name them this way:

`"<mine or company initials>_<ToolName>_<WidgetName>"`

In you case this will be something like `"ak_VertexDistance_InputCurrentLength"`.

**Why this naming?**
Few months ago I was writing a script to save a Maya scene somewhere on the network. I was trying to add some items to an `optionMenu` to my window, but whatever I was trying, the `optionMenu` remained empty. After two hours of unsuccessful researches, I realised that the item were added to an other `optionMenu` in an other of my tools. The widgets had the same generic name.

Your initials are optionnal but adding a `<ToolName>` is in my opinion mandatory if you want to differenciate the widgets of your different tools.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved two ways I think of:

**The first** is to create a CLASS surrounding all your functions and saving the textFieldButtonGrp in a class variable `self.textField = textFieldButtonGrp(...)`.
This means creating a class encapsulating all of your functions, adding an `__init__(self,*args)` function together with the rest, and probably adding self. everywhere it fails (function calls, calling variables...). And, as a plus, you will be able to save every item from the UI in a class variable, and use it in any funcion using self.variableName

**The second** aproach is to create the textField, keep it in a variable, and then pass it as an argument using that `buttonCommand=partial(functionname,variable)`

Where partial comes from:

```
from functools import partial
```

But the way to do this is first create the text field without the buttonCommand, and then execute the creation of the textField using edit mode (not create mode) [Short explanation about execution modes](https://books.google.es/books?id=6ErrBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA22&ots=wP4NGnBtct&dq=python%20maya%20create%20edit%20query%20mode&hl=es&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=python%20maya%20create%20edit%20query%20mode&f=false)

`textFieldButtonGrp(variableName, edit=True, buttonCommand=partial(function,variableName)`)

So you edit the text field to add this buttonCommand afterwards.

I haven't tested this, but I'm sure any of them will work, specially the first.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@DrHaze is correct, your UI elements will not have spaces in their names: when you create

In general,. using a class is the easiest way to make sure that the UI elements you need are accessible to your functions: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984667/replace-text-in-textfield-with-object-name-pymel/28993903#28993903) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609450/maya-python-using-data-from-ui/29683255#29683255) and extended discussion [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)

If you don't want to use a class you will need to make sure that the functions get the real name of your UI elements, not the name you are expecting.